# Pycountry: how to get country name, language name and alpha_3 and find matches from a language list

Tags: python, dataframe, country-codes, pycountry-convert

I have a list of languages and dialects.
For these languages I need to get Alpha_3 and country.name (if availavle).

```
import pycountry

my_langs = ['Aachen German', 'Aalsters', 'Abkhaz', 'Afrikaans', 'Albanian', 'Gheg', 'Altay', 'Old English†']

existing_iso3 = []
for lang in my_langs:
    existing_iso3.append(pycountry.languages.get(name=lang))
    

existing_iso3 = [x for x in existing_iso3 if x is not None]
existing_iso3
```

Output:

```
[Language(alpha_2='af', alpha_3='afr', name='Afrikaans', scope='I', type='L'),
 Language(alpha_2='sq', alpha_3='sqi', bibliographic='alb', name='Albanian', scope='M', type='L')]
```

Is there a way to remove this Language before the parenthesis and find country names for these languages?

So the output would be something like a df

| Language | Alpha_3 | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Afrikaans | afr | South Africa |
| Albanian | sqi | Albania |

Is it be also possible to look for a match within Languages? For example not for exact match of Aachen German but only German and return Germany